# Mumford's claim on the quasi-projectiveness of the coarse moduli of ppav over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, abelian-varieties, geometric-invariant-theory, coarse-moduli-spaces

In paragraph 3 of chapter 7 of Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory, the author proves that the coarse moduli space $A_{g,d,n}$ of abelian varieties of dimension $g$, with a degree $d^2$ polarization and a level $n$ structure, exists over $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$ and is quasi-projective over $\text{Spec }\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ for any prime number $p$.

He next claims that $A_{g,d,n}$ is in fact quasi-projective over $\text{Spec }\mathbb{Z}$ but does not provide a proof. How is this done nowadays?

Comment: If memory serves, this is proved in Faltings-Chai.

Comment: And in my thesis, Astérisque 129 (1985), VII, Th. 4.2. (Of course the question arises only for $n=1$).

Comment: @Moret-Bailly Thank you for this reference, it is really well explained. Would you like to post this as an answer so I can accept it and close the topic?